# How make an events target accessable in another function?

Tags: javascript, events, callback

I have the following code scenario, where right now `e.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild( e.target.parentNode );`is not accessable in `deleteUser`. Is there a way to connect it or any other `solution` ?

```
  // Delete users for ADMIN with GET 
 document.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {

      if (e.target.classList.contains( "btnDeleteUser" )) {
          /// get users based on id
          sUserId = e.target.getAttribute( "data-userId" );
          //console.log(sUserId);
          getAjax("api_delete_user.php?id=" + sUserId, deleteUser );
      }
  });

 function deleteUser ( ajUserDataFromServer ) {

                  if (ajUserDataFromServer.status == "ok") {

                      //console.log( "USER DELETED FROM THE DATABASE" );
                      e.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild( e.target.parentNode );

                  } else {

                      //console.log("USER NOT DELETED FROM THE DATABASE");
                      showErrorMessage( "Deleting User Failed - Try again" );

                  }
 }

  // Main ajax function using callback for getting data from the server
  function getAjax( sUrl, callback) {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {          
            ajDataFromServer = JSON.parse( this.responseText );
            callback( ajDataFromServer );
            }
        }

    ajax.open( "GET", sUrl, true );
    ajax.send();

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a thunk to pass the event object into a closure around your function.

A thunk is basically a way to delay passing of arguments to a function, When you call it you provide the first argument, it will return a function that takes the second argument, when you provide the second argument it will execute the function with both arguments in it's closure.

Basically instead of `foo(1, 2)` you would use `foo(1)(2)` to execute the underlying function.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  getAjax("api_delete_user.php?id=" + sUserId, deleteUser(e));
});

function deleteUser(e) {
  return function deleteUser(ajUserDataFromServer) {
    // do the delete
  }
}
```

or you could use `Function#bind` to pass through the event. It works much the same, however, you would need to modify your callback to accept the event object as an argument and the `this` context may not be what you expect in the ajax function.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  getAjax("api_delete_user.php?id=" + sUserId, deleteUser.bind(this, e));
});

function deleteUser(e, ajUserDataFromServer) {
  // do the delete
}
```

Comment: Performance and security - wise which of the above solutions is the most optimal ?

Comment: ...also do I need to add the event object to my `getAjax function`? 
  function getAjax( sUrl, callback) {
            // code
            callback( e, ajDataFromServer );
           // code
  } Eventually it works without doing that but if you declare it as a parameter in the callback then would´nt you need to call it as well ? Or what it is the consequence of not doing it ?

Comment: They are about the same. There should be no security concerns for either and performance should not be a concern unless you are calling this function thousands of times in a row every second. No you don't need to add the event object to the getAjax function, only to it's callback.

Comment: I like the `function#bind` solution more, feels more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

- An approach is passing the event variable to your function `deleteUser`

**Recommendation:** add an id to your elements and find it within your function `deleteUser`

```
// Delete users for ADMIN with GET 
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  if (e.target.classList.contains("btnDeleteUser")) {
    /// get users based on id
    sUserId = e.target.getAttribute("data-userId");
    //console.log(sUserId);

    // You need to pass a function who receives the param from your function getAjax.
    // The function getAjax will call a callback, in this case, the function we are passing.  
    // Therefore, when the getAjax function calls: callback( ajDataFromServer ); 
    // 'fromServer' will be the passed value 'ajDataFromServer'.

    getAjax("api_delete_user.php?id=" + sUserId, function(fromServer) {
      deleteUser(fromServer, e);
    });
  }
});

function deleteUser(ajUserDataFromServer, e) {
  if (ajUserDataFromServer.status == "ok") {
    //console.log( "USER DELETED FROM THE DATABASE" );
    e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode);
  } else {
    //console.log("USER NOT DELETED FROM THE DATABASE");
    showErrorMessage("Deleting User Failed - Try again");

  }
}
```

Comment: What does `fromServer`parameter do ?

Comment: @codeDragon it's the passed param from `ajax.onreadystatechange = function() { ... callback( ajDataFromServer ); }`

Comment: why do you need to pass it again inside `function(fromServer)`?

Comment: @codeDragon just to get your local variable event `e` be passed to your function `deleteUser`.

Comment: Why isn´t this enough `getAjax("api_delete_user.php?id=" + sUserId, function() {
      deleteUser(fromServer, e);
    });`?

Comment: @codeDragon because `fromServer` will be undeclared variable.

Comment: yeah I tested, but I still don´t understand the theory behind.

Comment: @codeDragon I've updated the answer with more comments within the code snippet.